# Flutter desktop - drop out files

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I use this plugin to drag files from desktop to my flutter app:
https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_drop

There is any plugin to do the opposite?

So drop out from my flutter app to desktop.

Thanks.